# Colision detection p5.js

Tags: javascript, collision, detection, p5.js, pong

just trying to make a simple pong game in p5.js. I have very recently gotten into JavaScript and can't manage to figure out collision detection between the ball and the bat. I have tried a few ways of doing it but it mostly just stopped my code from running.. etc.. would love any help!

Here is my source code:

```
function setup() {     
  createCanvas(750, 750);
    } 

var x = 50;    
var y = 50;    
var direction = 5;    
var arrow = 0;    
var ball;    
var bat;

function draw() {     
  background(220);    
  fill ('white');    
  ball = ellipse (x, y, 50, 50);    
  x = x + direction;

  if (x > width - 25){    
    direction = -5;    
  }

  if (x < 25) {    
    direction = 5;    
  }

  x++;    
  y++;

  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){    
    arrow += 7;    
  }

  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){    
    arrow += -7;    
  }

  fill ('black');    
  bat = rect(arrow, 600, 150, 15);
  }
```

Comment: "stopped my code from running"  Whats your issue?  Whats your question?   What do you expect the code snippet to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad, but basically what you want to do is imagine a "bounding rectangle" around the ball, and then use rectangle-rectangle collision to check whether the ball is colliding with a paddle. If it is, "bounce" the ball by multiplying its horizontal speed by -1.

I wrote a tutorial on collision detection available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection), but the basic `if` statement looks like this:

```
if(rectOneRight > rectTwoLeft && rectOneLeft < rectTwoRight && rectOneBottom > rectTwoTop && rectOneTop < rectTwoBottom){
```

You also might want to read the **Collision Detection with Moving Objects** section of that tutorial. It's written for Processing, but everything applies to P5.js as well.

If you're having trouble getting it working, then please start over with a more basic sketch that just shows two hard-coded rectangles. Make them turn red when they're not colliding. Then work your way up from there. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions, so you'll have much better luck if you post a specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question. Good luck.