# Two rectangles colliding

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm making a simple game. I have one stationary rectangle and one moving only on the y axis. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjP0r.png).
The right car is moving down. The two cars have a width of 40 and a height of 80.

When I check collision like this it doesn't work properly.

```
if (dist(other_car.x, other_car.y, main_car.pos.x, main_car.pos.y) < 40) {
  console.log("colliding");
}
```

How do I make it more accurate?

Comment: you should check for collision of the enclosing boxes of each car

Comment: but how? I'm new to programming.

Comment: see the answer here: its already defined: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022269/collision-detection-between-two-rectangles-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colision detection p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650655/colision-detection-p5-js)

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're doing circle-circle collision detection. You want to be doing rectangle-rectangle collision detection.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection. It's written for Processing, but all of the ideas apply to P5.js as well.

Googling "rectangle-rectangle collision detection" will also return a ton of results. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping!